# Increase the font size of text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, ssrs-2008, report, bids

I have a report where I want the font size of the number to be really huge so when its printed, that number is visible from a distance. 
Below is a text box with the background color as yellow. The font size is 200pt, which is the highest BIDS would accept. 
Is there a way to increase the font size so that it at least is double the size shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: i am using SSRS. The number is coming from a sql database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using inches instead of points to specify the font size.   For instance, set it to "2.5in" and see how that looks.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: I tried 2.5 inches but the size remains the same which it should have as 2.5in=200pt.

Comment: Well, ok, then what about 4in?

Comment: You cant increase the font size beyond 200pt or 2.5 inches in BIDS. I converted the text to Image using VB.net, then I increased the size of the image. So that worked for me. Thank you for your help and time @Tab Alleman.